# What is the tense type of "I was keen to work with him"?

Tags: tenses

As per my understanding, if a particular sentence starts with "I was", then it could be a past participle tense.

But the past participle follows this format,

> subject + was/were + verb + 'ing'

But in my example, 'I was keen to work with him', there is no '-ing' form. But it is still considered as a grammatically correct sentence. I'm confused as to how this is correct.

Can someone help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, *was* is simply the past tense of the verb *to be.* It is the main verb of the sentence.

*I was thinking* is actually the past continuous tense. In this case *to be* is an [auxiliary verb](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/auxiliary_verbs.htm).

Answer (score 0):

*Was* is a "linking verb" in your sentence. It links the subject (*I*) to the subject complement, in this case, the adjective *keen*. This is different than the present progressive form, where *to be* "helps" a present participle, e.g. *I was working with him*.